# htaccess to redirect everything to index with exceptions

Tags: .htaccess

How would I redirect all files and folders to index with the exception of only a hand full?

Right now I have this, which is redirecting everything, included needed files such as css and js files for site functionality.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following above the RewriteRule.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(cssfolder|otherfolders)
```

If you would apply the above to your .htaccess, it would like something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(cssfolder|otherfolder1|otherfolder2|otherfolder3)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: do i put $1 in place of %{REQUEST_URI} ?

Comment: also, can I use | as many times as I would like for designated pages/directories which would not be redirected ?

Comment: yep that helps a lot thank you Bob, one final question. I see you mention only folder names there, is it possible to add files to that list as well like so (cssfolder|otherfolder|thankyou.php) ?

Comment: yes, but you have to declare them as thankyou\.php I believe. Not sure on that one though.

Answer (score 0):

Try Options -Indexes on the top of htaccess Script

For example if we need to redirect some special extension files to another directory we can implement our htaccess like these

Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .(svc)$
RewriteRule (.fr.*) directoryname/Index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

Now all the requests except *.fr will redirect to index.php and *.fr will redirect to the direcoryname/Index.php